# Is it possible to reclaim the memory used by an initrd?

Tags: linux, memory, ramdisk, initrd

I'm developing a boot process for an embedded device. Currently I'm using an initrd (uncompressed it's 4 megs) to be able to setup my real root partition before continuing to boot (I have to select a partition based on some information, and overlay another using unionfs).

However, I'm concerned that the memory that was used for the initrd filesystem is permanently reserved for that use, even though it's only necessary for less than a few seconds of boot time. The device only has 256 megs of RAM, and 4 megs of this seems significant.

- Is there a way to reclaim this memory?
- If I were to use initramfs instead of initrd, would this buy me anything?
- Is there another option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory used by initrd/initramfs is freed after it is done with ie. when real root fs is mounted. So normally you should have to worry about this. Your question reveals that you're not using the initrd/initramfs as your run-time root fs, so the memory used for it is freed automatically.

For more details, see [initrd part of kernel documentation](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/initrd.html) under the heading of "Changing the root device".

Comment: I don't see anything in that document that says I wouldn't have to worry about it, but it does look like I should be unmounting the initrd then freeing the RAM myself. However, when I try to unmount the initrd, I get "device or resource busy". Accepted because that document does contain the answer :)

Comment: Never mind! Turns out devtmpfs was still mounted under the initrd directory.